# how to use sed to find a patter and replace the rest of the line with another word

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

i want to search "oidc_client_id:" and replace like " oidc_client_id: abc123" but at the same time in that line there should not be "os_clud_1"
oidc_client_id: os_cloud_1
oidc_client_secret: “Place your secret”

i want to remove "xyx.io" and replace it with "google.com"
oidc_provider_metadata_url: https://xyx.io/auth/realms/cloud/.well-known/openid-configuration

using this in jenkins with parameters

i tried few thing but like

sed -i 's/OIDC_CLI_ID/${IdpRealmName}/g' ${SSO_FILE_PATH}
sed -i 's/OIDC_CLI_SECRET/${OidcClientId}/g' ${SSO_FILE_PATH}

Answer (score 0):

You should have provided a "sanitized" version of your ${SSO_FILE_PATH} so that the community knows exactly what you are working with.

**IF** I correctly understood your problem, you need something of the following form.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Default Values (if desired)
#ID="abc123"
#SEC="Place your secret"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --id ) ID="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
        --secret ) SEC="$2" ; shift ; shift ;;
        * ) echo "\n\t Invalid option specified on the command line.  Valid options:  [ --id {} | --secret {} ] .\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${ID}" -o -z "${SEC}" ]
then
    echo "\n\t Unable to proceed.  Required values defined for each of --id and --secret .\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 
fi

PREF_1="oidc_client_id:"
PREF_2="oidc_client_secret:"

SSO_FILE_PATH="./dumdum.txt"

#create substitute for normal template
cat >${SSO_FILE_PATH} <<-!EnDoFiNpUt
    other_header ;
    oidc_client_id: jackAndJill ;
    oidc_client_secret: standardSecret ;
    other_data ;
!EnDoFiNpUt

awk -v id="${ID}" -v sec="${SEC}" -v p1="${PREF_1}" -v p2="${PREF_2}" '{
    inbuf=$0 ;

    if( index( inbuf, p1 ) > 0 ){
        inbuf=sprintf("%s %s ;", p1, id ) ;
    } ;
    if( index( inbuf, p2 ) > 0 ){
        inbuf=sprintf("%s %s ;", p2, sec ) ;
    } ;

    print inbuf ;
}' <${SSO_FILE_PATH} >${SSO_FILE_PATH}.tmp

mv -fv ${SSO_FILE_PATH}.tmp ${SSO_FILE_PATH}

cat ${SSO_FILE_PATH}
```

Session log for my test:

```
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ test.sh --id abc123 --secret "Place your secret"
renamed './dumdum.txt.tmp' -> './dumdum.txt'
other_header ;
oidc_client_id: abc123 ;
oidc_client_secret: Place your secret ;
other_data ;
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$
```